# Android: RadioButton Not Resetting

Tags: android, radio-button

I have been banging my head about this for hours. My layout and activity files are below. If I run the app, A is selected by default, as intended. If I then select B and rotate, I expect the selection to return to the default of A and that is the id logged as the radioButtonGroup.checkedRadioButtonId. The problem is that B is still displayed on the app itself. Why??

```
`
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">`



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/employment_button_layout"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radio_button_group"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/a_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="A" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/b_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="B" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/c_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="C" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


package com.cs211d.loanreview

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.RadioButton
import android.widget.RadioGroup

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var radioButtonGroup : RadioGroup
    private lateinit var aButton : RadioButton
    private lateinit var bButton : RadioButton
    private lateinit var cButton : RadioButton


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        radioButtonGroup = findViewById(R.id.radio_button_group)
        aButton = findViewById(R.id.a_button)
        bButton = findViewById(R.id.b_button)
        cButton = findViewById(R.id.c_button)

        Log.d("oncreate", radioButtonGroup.checkedRadioButtonId.toString())

    }



    fun onClick (view : View){
        Log.d("TESTING evaluate status", radioButtonGroup.checkedRadioButtonId.toString())
    }
}
`
```

I know that I can manually save the state in the bundle, but it's my understanding that otherwise the state is NOT saved. And that is what it appears is happening based on the logged ID. But I cannot figure out why the display doesn't match that.

Answer (score 0):

When the device is rotated, the activity is recreated and the radio button should be reset to its default value. However, if you want to explicitly reset the radio button to its default value when the device is rotated, you can do so by implementing the onConfigurationChanged() method in your activity.

```
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation">
...
</activity>
```

You can then try to add the following code in your code

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    defaultRadioButton.setChecked(true);
}
```

Maybe this helps

Comment: Thanks. I know that you can reset it manually. And I know that it *should* reset to its default value. I want to understand why it is NOT doing that with the code as-is.